# Same formula with different results in R and excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2010, r

I have calculated the load for 3 water quality parameters in R for specific days for the whole year using this formula.

[image]

I calculated 7 scenarios using the previous formula. Each scenario represent 1 day of the week (Monday of each week, Tuesday of each week....) for the whole year.

Using 1 year [dataset](https://www.dropbox.com/s/4dxn9knbo3y644g/Data.csv?dl=0) (dataset and excel calculations could be downloaded from [here](https://www.dropbox.com/sh/w8h7xj96fehg14f/AADKUpwze7TZAcsNK8Wb2m-_a?dl=0)), I have used (tapply) function in R to calculate the load using the previous formula

```
FWNH4Week=tapply( 1:length( NH4 ), as.factor( Weekday ), function( x ) ((sum(Flow[x]*NH4[x])/sum(Flow[x]))*sum(Flow)))
```

I have calculated the same formula in [excel](http://www.dropbox.com/s/j4u0mq3sgj0flbm/Formula.xlsx?dl=0) before. By comparing the results I got from [excel](http://www.dropbox.com/s/j4u0mq3sgj0flbm/Formula.xlsx?dl=0) and R, they are similar for 2 days and different for the rest of the days. I'd appreciate if you could check the R function and excel calculation and could help me to figure out why I got different results using the same formula?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

I really don't know why you would want to do that, as the formula is for annual load.
Why would there be a weekly cycle that fits exactly on weekdays?
But if you want to do it anyways (maybe in in industrial waste water setting?), this is how I'd go at it:

```
weekday <- rep(1:7, 25)
set.seed(007)
Flow <- cumsum(rnorm(25*7)) + 20
NH4 <- Flow + rnorm(25*7)
plot(Flow, type="l")
lines(NH4, col=2)
# anual sum:
sum(Flow)*  sum(Flow*NH4) / sum(Flow) # 228 660
# per weekday
sapply( unique(weekday), function(i)
  {
  wd <- which(weekday==i)
  sum(Flow[wd])*  sum(Flow[wd]*NH4[wd]) / sum(Flow[wd])
  } )
# each ca 32 000 , a seventh of annual load
```

Regards,
Berry

Comment: Many thanks for your help. Indeed my formula for annual load but sampling on daily basis is difficult because of the high cost of sampling and analysis. As a result, we use weekly samples to check how the annual loads calculated by (52) samples differ from the annual load calculated by (365) samples